# How do I calculate the frequency of ICMP requests being received by a Linux machine?

Tags: ruby, linux, perl

I've been trying to calculate the frequency per minute of ICMP requests being received by my machine.

I tried using tcpdump and saving the results into a text file, and then grepping the time stamps to calculate the difference between them, but that only resulted in lots of delay.

My approach was:

```
tcpdump -i eth1 icmp[0]==8 | tee abc.txt
grep -Eo '^[^ ]+' abc.txt
perl -e 'open$T,pop;while(1){while(<$T>){ ++$f{$_}>10 and print "[$f{$_}]$_" for /(\d+:\d+)/ }sleep 1;seek $T,0,1}' abc.txt
```

Is there a way to calculate the frequency of the ICMP requests being received on my machine without any use of files?

I am pinging from a machine to other and want to calculate the frequency of pings being received at the receiving end.

Comment: Your question is very broad and not well suited for Stack Overflow because you're fishing for answers in Ruby and/or Perl, and haven't showed any code you've written, nor an error. You should probably ask this question on http://poweruser.com, which focuses on the OS level. If you want a programming solution because you haven't tried writing something, you're definitely off topic. See http://sscce.org/ for how to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap tcpdump in a script, no files involved. Note the `-l` option to tcpdump, which says do line buffering. If you leave it out you'll get buffered output which isn't likely what you want.

```
sout = IO.popen("sudo  tcpdump -l -i any icmp[0]==8 2>&1")
line = sout.gets
while (!line.nil?) 
  p line
  #fiddle with line and do time
  line = sout.gets
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to capture and analyze the packets. The kernel exports counters in `/proc/net/snmp`.